# I need to symbolically link every directory and file in a target directory

Tags: powershell

Directories and files could change in the target, so the script needs to parse the directory on each run. Say c:\PS\ contains all of the targets and c:\DS contains all the links. I have tried something like

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "c:\ps"
foreach ($file in $files){
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "C:\DS\" -Target $file.FullName
}
```

My attempts are falling short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mainly 2 issues with your code, the first one, `$path` is not defined and the second one, double-quotes in `"c:\DS\$d.Name"` are not allowing `$d.Name` to expand, you can use [Subexpression operator `$( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#subexpression-operator--) for this.

```
$dir = Get-ChildItem c:\ps\
foreach($d in $dir) {
    New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "c:\DS\$($d.Name)" -Target $d.FullName
}
```

Above should create a symlink in the `C:\DS\` directory where each link has the name of their *target folder*. One thing to consider, this could require you to run PowerShell with admin permissions.

Comment: Awesome that got it.

Comment: Nope wait. Thats just directories. I need files also. I got it. I just removed -Directory  and all is good.

Comment: @4evernoob well, you were using `?{$_.PSISContainer}` before the edit, I just assumed that's what you were looking for :P